# How to write query to match across all tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sphinx

I am new to mysql, php and sphinx.

I want to return name of the tables if given `query text` resides in it.
I have `query text` which can fall in any of these categories state or county. I am sending `query text` it via `POSTMAN` to `API` and trying to print results in response

> but it's returning 0 matches found

which is worng. Because query text is present in one of tables which I'm passing. E.g. query text is Alabama, is present in state table but still says no results found.

php code

```
$cl = new SphinxClient();
$cl->SetServer('127.0.0.1', 9312);
$cl->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED);
$result = $cl->Query($query, 'detectkeyword');
print_r($result);
```

Sphinx.conf code

```
sql_query = \
Select UUID_SHORT() AS sphinxid, 'state' as keyword from region \
UNION ALL \
Select UUID_SHORT() AS sphinxid, 'county' as keyword from county;

sql_attr_uint = sphinxid
sql_field_string = keyword
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont seem to have a separate field to actually 'match' against,

Need something like...

```
Select UUID_SHORT() AS sphinxid, region_name as text, 'state' as keyword from region \
```

Otherwise your query was only matching against the 'state' keyword itself.